# How can I print array element abreatsly?

Tags: python, arrays, loops, for-loop, arraylist

```
array = [a, b, c]
for i in array:
  print(i),
```

output:

```
a
b
c
```

I would like this:
abc

Comment: print(array[0]+array[1]+array[2])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `end` argument of `print` as:

```py
array = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for i in array:
  print(i, end='')
```

Answer (score 1):

In python 2

```
from sys import stdout
array = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for i in array:
    stdout.write(i)
```

In Python 3 it becomes easy

```
for i in array:
    print(i, end='')
```

For lower versions

```
from __future__ import print_function
for i in array:
    print(i, end="")
```

Also using `join`

```
print(''.join(array))
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing quotes in your array definition, it should be like
`['a',  'b',  'c']` or `["a", "b", "c"]` but not `[a, b, c]`, if you're referring to strings and not variables.

One way to do what you're trying to do is this:

`print(''.join(array))`

This tells Python to print all the elements of `array` separated by the empty string, that is print them one after the other.

Answer (score -1):

If you are handling larger lists, this method is not a good idea. But it gets the job done.

```
array = ['a', 'b', 'c']
print(array[0]+array[1]+array[2])
```